# Fancybox: display both nav arrows on all gallery images, with "previous" and "next" dimmed (but visible) on first and last images, respectively

Tags: navigation, fancybox, fancybox-2

In my Fancybox gallery, I modified the Fancybox CSS to display the navigation arrows at all times (not just on hover), and set the opacity to increase from 0.7 to 1.0 on hover. However, the previous and next arrows do not appear on the first and last image, respectively, because they are non-functional (I have "loop" set to "false"). Having only one of the two arrows showing on those images makes the nav look unbalanced, so I want both arrows to show at all times, but want the nonfunctional arrows be even more transparent than the functional arrow in its non-hover state, say 0.3, so that the user understands it's non-operational.

I altered the js by changing this code:

```
if (current.loop || current.index > 0) {
$(current.tpl.prev).appendTo(F.outer).bind('click.fb', F.prev);}
```

to this:

```
if (current.loop || current.index >= 0) {
$(current.tpl.prev).appendTo(F.outer).bind('click.fb', F.prev);}
```

and did the same for the "next" arrow.

This does cause both arrows to appear, but I can't figure out how to have the non-functional buttons on the first and last image appear dimmer than the functional one. Here's an example page (I reverted to the original js so users wouldn't be confused): 
http://transweb.sjsu.edu/mntrc/events/2012/gallery1.html

Any help achieving this would be appreciated. I am js-impaired (but not css-impaired), so please give complete code examples, indicating how to integrate it in my current code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you most probably know, to show navigation arrows permanently visible you set this css rule

```
.fancybox-nav span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

this will, or course, show the prev/next navigation arrows ONLY if there is a previous or next element (previous arrow won't show with the first element of the gallery if `loop` is set to `false` for instance)

In order to show the "*non-functional*" arrows **all the time** (and dimmed), you can append them on the fly using the `beforeShow` callback within your custom fancybox script like :

```
beforeShow: function(){
 // evaluates if this is the FIRST element of the gallery
 // if so, appends a dimmed (non-functional) PREVIOUS navigation arrow
 if(this.index == 0) {
   $(this.tpl.prev).appendTo($.fancybox.outer).css({"opacity":0.6});
 } else 
 // evaluates if this is the LAST element of the gallery
 // if so, appends a dimmed (non-functional) NEXT navigation arrow
 if( this.index < this.group.length){
   $(this.tpl.next).appendTo($.fancybox.outer).css({"opacity":0.6});
 }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your quick response. JS Lint found an error in the first line of code, saying: "Use '===' to compare with '0'" So I changed it from == to ===. I also changed the opacity of the  non-functional buttons to 0.3 because I wanted them to be noticeably dimmer than the functional ones in their non-hovered state, which are at 0.7. You can see the results at http://transweb.sjsu.edu/mntrc/events/2012/gallery1.html.

Comment: One last question (and please tell me if this should be a separate posting): during transitions, the "next" and "previous" buttons seem to appear at two different speeds; they also seem to have a different transition effect from the image itself. I would like for either both buttons to stay fully visible during transitions, or for both to use the same transition effect as the image itself and appear at the same moment. Can you help?

Comment: @user1621036 the issue is that nav/prev buttons are appended to fancybox outer every time for every element of the gallery. Why? because they are re-positioned according to the fancybox container. I guess you would need to modify the original js file to append them to the `body` instead (don't count me in) .... this is actually what the buttons helper does, check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs "extended functionality", maybe is what you need.

Comment: And yet I don't need them repositioned according to the container, since I have specified that they remain in the same position throughout. I tried using the button helper but didn't care for the supplied images and didn't want to spend the time rewriting the css for a different sprite. Perhaps I will, though, because I am definitely not rewriting the original js. Any other ideas? (Thanks again, btw.)